# rviz compiled against OGRE

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when i enter **rosrun rviz rviz** in terminal the following appears

**[ INFO] : rviz version 1.10.14**

**[ INFO]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.4 (Cthugha)**

I use amd radeon HD 8***M series

I tried to uninstall OGRE 1.7.4; the uninstall of it contain the uninstall of rviz hydro, the install of hydro rviz contain the install of OGRE 1.7.4. how could I solve such a problem. How could I use hydro rviz

Anyone knows how to solve such a problem? thank you!!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/152961/rviz-compiled-against-ogre/) by [Crystal](https://answers.ros.org/users/14821/crystal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-04-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-04-14**:
Could you tell us why you are uninstalling OGRE 1.7.4?

**Comment by [Crystal](https://answers.ros.org/users/14821/crystal/) on 2014-04-15**:
cause i came across some problems when i run rviz and i tried some method to solve them. when i tried this one, I find such a thing and I wonder the reason for that.

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-04-15**:
@Crystal: Did you have same error that is described on this page ( http://answers.ros.org/question/150801/segmentation-fault-at-rosrun-rviz-rviz/ )? If so, I gave up and reinstalled both ROS and Ubuntu. Sorry!! If you want to ask the question, you should post it again. Question is changed.

**Comment by [Crystal](https://answers.ros.org/users/14821/crystal/) on 2014-04-15**:
oh....more or less the same...sometimes I can use some times not....thank you for your advice! But I have reinstalled both of them 2 times....I think it is the problem of my graphic card driver. I will try some other methods, if they will not work. I think I should reinstall them again...thank you~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OGRE is a 3D graphics library that is used by Rviz; you can't have rviz without it. This is why the package manager installs it when you install rviz.

If you want to use a different version of OGRE, you can build rviz from source.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Crystal](https://answers.ros.org/users/14821/crystal/) on 2014-04-15**:
thank you!! and I have another problem that when I open a file in rviz it shut down. why is that, how could I solve such a problem? thank you for your help!

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-04-16**:
You should ask this as a new question, and include the command-line arguments you're passing to rviz, and possibly a link to the file you're trying to open.